# Can a disjunction distribute over disjunction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is $P \vee (Q \vee R) \equiv (P \vee Q) \vee (P \vee R) $? The same applies for conjunctions right? Sorry if this is obvious, I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Can you write a truth table?

Comment: If only one of and, or is used, the product of several is both commutative and associative, and idempotent [p or p = p, p and p = p]

Comment: Yes but it is useless because $P \lor P \equiv P$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

1. Conjunction distribute over disjunction $P \wedge (Q \lor R) = (P \wedge Q) \lor (P \wedge R)$.
2. Disjunction distribute over conjunction $P \lor (Q \wedge R) = (P \lor Q) \wedge (P \lor R)$.

I would not say that disjunction distributes over disjunction or that conjunction distribute over conjunction. However, conjunctions and disjunctions are both commutative; i.e., $P \star Q = Q \star P$ and associative; i.e., $(P \star Q) \star R = P \star (Q \star R)$ where $\star$ could be either $\wedge$ or $\lor$.

Therefore, $P \lor (Q \lor R) = (P \lor Q) \lor R = P \lor Q \lor R$ without ambiguity. Similarly, $(P \lor Q) \lor (P \lor R) = P \lor Q \lor P \lor R$. Since $P \lor P$ is equivalent to $P$ the two propositions are effectively logically equivalent and you could check this by means of a truth table. However, what you call "distribution of disjunction over disjunction" seems more of a contortion rather than a useful property.